# Accessing ddeboer/Imap Mail Header

Tags: php, imap

I'm accessing a mailbox using [ddeboer/imap](https://github.com/ddeboer/imap). Connecting to the Server and retrieving Messages ist not a problem. But `$message->getHeaders()` returns the following (shortened Version):

```
Ddeboer\Imap\Message\Headers Object
(
    [storage:ArrayIterator:private] => Array
        (
            [date] => Fri, 5 Jul 2019 07:00:47 +0200
            [subject] => Test Mail
            [message_id] => <108a4850-284e-170a-2c7d-b6f9g5218202@test.de>

            [fromaddress] => "Test" <test@test.de>
            [from] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [personal] => Test
                            [mailbox] => test
                            [host] => test.de
                        )

                )

            [deleted] =>  
            [draft] =>  
            [msgno] => 1
            [maildate] =>  5-Jul-2019 07:00:49 +0200
            [size] => 223715
            [udate] => 1562302849
        )

)
```

How am I supposed to access the Information e.g. `udate` or `from->mailbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the get method and add the path

```
$message->getHeaders()->get('udate'):
$message->getHeaders()->get('from')[0]->mailbox
```